# How to find files that user and group have the same permission

Tags: command-line, grep, ls

I would like to find the files that the user and the others have the same permissions. I tried `ls -l` and `egrep` but I don't know how I'll say that position 234 will be the same with position 567.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `find` is what you looking for.

Comment: Your title says "user and group" whereas you say "the user and the others" in the body - what are you looking for exactly? Consider [edit]ing your question with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: your question is unclear about whether you want to find files with the same **user** and **group** permissions, or with the same **user** and **others** permissions. Based on your mention of positions 234 and 567 in the mode string, I am assuming the former here - although the same methods may easily be adapted to the latter.*

If you wanted to find files whose **u**ser, **g**roup, and **o**thers (`ugo`) permissions are *all* the same, that's fairly straightforward using the `find` command:

```
find . -type f \( -perm 000 -o -perm 111 -o -perm 222 -o -perm 333 -o -perm 444 -o -perm 555 -o -perm 666 -o -perm 777 \)
```

Unfortunately to do the same for just `ug` is much more work - you'd need to test all 8 possible `o` bytes for each pair of equal `ug` bytes. You could automate that however using bash brace expansion to construct an array of `-perm` tests:

```
perms=( $(printf -- '-o -perm %s\n' {00..77..11}{0..7}) )
```

then

```
find . -type f \( -false "${perms[@]}" \)
```

---

Probably a better approach is to use something that can work with the mode bits arithmetically - for example via perl's `stat` function:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -le '
  foreach (@ARGV) {print $_ unless (((stat)[2] & 00070) << 3 ^ (stat)[2]) & 00700}
' {} +
```

which extracts the group and user mode bits and XORs them - the result being zero (false) if they are the same.

---

If you're set on doing it by parsing a textual representation of the file mode, a slightly more robust way than parsing the output of `ls` might be something like:

```
find . -type f -printf '%m\t%p\0' | 
  gawk -v RS='\0' 'match($1,/([0-7])([0-7])/,m) && m[2] == m[1] {print $2}'
```

(you could use plain `.` instead of `[0-7]` in the regex, but I feel that the latter makes the intent clearer).

Answer (score 1):

`stat` solution:

```
stat --format '%a %n' * | grep -E '^([0-9])\1'
```

---

or for use in a script with null-delimiter, get the file names only:

```
stat --printf '%a\t%n\0' * | grep -Ez '^([0-9])\1' | cut -z -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally discourage [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but here:

```bsh
ls -l | sed -En '/^.(...)...\1/p'
```

Comment: Thank you all very much