# Display files that have additional rights for group and others that the user does not have

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

I have a problem to solve for a university class I am taking.
I need a command that lists files in a directory that have a group or others permission that is set, but it is not set for the owner (such files could have security problems if someone other than the owner has more rights on a file).

How can I do that and display the result as the file name followed by the additional right that appeared for others or for group (for example in g-r or o-x form)?

Comment: We usually do not do homework here. `find` can retrieve files based on many different criteria.

Comment: This might give you some ideas: [How to find files that user and group have the same permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296163/how-to-find-files-that-user-and-group-have-the-same-permission)

Comment: Read `man find stat`.